# Redirect to a subdirectory

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a dictionary website that uses WordPress. Now the url for any term like "myterm" is in the form :http://domain.com/myterm. I want it to redirect to http://domain.com/definition/myterm. I don't know how to use regex for this kind of redirection. Also some urls such as domain.com/contact-Us and domain.com/FAQ exist that i don't want to redirect to /definition/Contact-us and /definition/FAQ. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in htaccess

```
RedirectMatch ^/myterm$ /definition/myterm
```

if myterm is a dynmic path, then you can use Regex capture group to capture the path value ,it will be saved as $1 for reuse in target path

```
 RedirectMatch ^/(.*)$ /definition/$1
```

To exclude specific paths from redirection, you can use

```
 RedirectMatch ^/((?!contect-us|FAQ).*)$ /definition/$1
```

and to negate more paths, just add them inside the capture group seperated by a pipe foo|bar|foobar.

Edit :

You also need to exclude the directory from redirect, so that it can not redirect to itself.

Try this

```
 RedirectMatch ^/((?!contect-us|FAQ|defination).*)$ /definition/$1
```

replace "defination" with name of your folder in pattern and target.

Comment: Thank you so much Starkeen. But it creates a recursive directory for me. For example the redirected url for a term like "Pixel" is domain.com/definition/definition/definition/definition/definition/definition/definition/definition/definition/pixel. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have any other Redirects in htaccess?

Comment: Yes, However, they are added automatically by wordpress.

Comment: here is the portion of my htaccess with redirects: http://www.freeuploadsite.com/do.php?id=83108

Comment: Aamirhosain the problem is that your wp rules are conflicting with this redirect, that is why The url redirection is going in infinite loop.

Comment: I don't know anything about this regex redirects. Are these rules necessary? Can i remove the conflicting ones?

Comment: OK, Thank you very much.

Comment: @AmirHosain I am sorry, my mistake, i forgot to exclude the folder. see the edit. This should work now.

Comment: Yeah, but now it redirects to /definition/index.php. i think it is because of the last wordpress redirect i sent to you. I mean: RewriteRule . /index.php [L], what should i do now?

Comment: all of the urls now redirect to /definition/index.php

Comment: Yes its because of that, put this redirect above other rules in your htacce.

Comment: I placed the rule you proposed above the others. (You mean this?) but nothing changed. The domain.com redirects to /definition/index.php too. Should it be excluded?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved. I used the redirect proposed by Starkeen. However, not in the .htaccess file. I used Simple 301 Redirects. It works properly without conflicting with WordPress rules.